# Excel Add In Debugging

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, vsto, add-in

I am just a beginner in excel add-in's.
Created excel add-in and wrote a simple variable assignment code in startup event.

My code

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string path = this.Application.ThisWorkbook.Path;
}
```

When F5 is pressed from visual studio, new empty excel file is opened and breakpoint hits this event.
Ideally you want to test the add-in on existing excel file to check modifications that your add-in is expected to do? Can the existing file be used for debugging?

Comment: Please re-phrase your question.

Comment: What is your problem more precisely. You are having problem debuging your addin with existing files?

Comment: Yes. that's correct.when I press f5, addin debugging point is hit with new excel file launched from visual studio.Want to debug with existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the code `string path = this.Application.ThisWorkbook.Path;` from this startup code to WorkbookOpen handler code.

This is because, during normal startup of addins, there is no workbook already loaded.
Most of the time you will get `null` for `ThisWorkbook` in startup time. So during startup of code, add event handler for handling `WorkbookOpen` event.

In the method which handles the `WorkbookOpen` Event, add your code to get the path of file.

Now for debugging:

(Default and Recommended)

In VS press F5.
In the launched Excel, open your excel file and start debugging.

OR

Start Excel. Open your file.
In VS, goto Tools->Attach To Process-> Find Excel.exe and double click.

OR

In project properties, Debug-> Select start external program -> Type the full path to access and add the excel file full path as argument

Comment: All 3 do not work.
1)Attach to process does not hit breakpoint , even though existing excel is open.
2)When F5 is pressed,add-In startup code runs on newly opened excel already, hence opening new excel using open menu has no effect.
3)Do you example of this?

Comment: Well these methods are used when a direct method is not supplied for debugging libraries. I have many example of these. Can you elaborate your question and show some code? Where you are putting breakpoints...

Comment: Are you putting breakpoint on a method which handles the event of WorkbookOpen?